# Is Vue.js susceptible to cascading updates?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

Talks by Tom Occhino and others speaking on React have referenced Angular's 2-way bindings as a source of cascading updates and something that made Angular difficult to reason about.

I understand the general idea of cascading updates and how having control flow weaving in and out of framework and app code could pose a challenge for debugging, though I've never coded in Angular to have experienced it myself.

My question is whether anyone familiar enough with the cascading updates and debugging challenges mentioned by the React folks can speak to whether it applies to the 2-way binding (or other aspects of) Vue?

*Side note: I have read that it's possible to use 1-way data flow and Redux/Vuex in Vue to make it work more like a React/Redux app.  I'm asking specifically about the basic 2-way binding that appears commonly used with Vue.*

Comment: The two way binding syntax in vue is just syntactic sugar for the 1-way data flow.  It might be interesting to note that in the C# world, XAML has two way binding and is also prone to the same kinds of cascading event storms as Angular.

Comment: This makes me think about why React may not suffer from the problem.  I think the view being re-rendered as a result of state changing would probably only happen if you fired an event in `componentWillReceiveProps` or other lifecycle methos that will cause `setState` to be called.  In other words, if you want cascading updates in React, you have to work for them, where in 2-way binding  you can easily get into the problem scenario if you're not aware of the danger and are conscientious about avoiding it.  Is that fair to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer is, it depends. You can in fact use 2-way data binding in Vue, but you can also use it in a one way manner.

Vuex/Redux is a state management pattern, as such it can help you manage memory, but you can still have a cascading update problem with that. I think personally, although the cascading update point that was made is valid, most of the problem is how people structure Parent and Child components. There is this concept of "dumb components" and "smart components" that people have mentioned before, meaning some component are dumb and simply hold child components that are stateful and thus smart, while it itself know very little about state.

If too many of your components are "smart" then one state change might affect all your components thus causing an update on all components. The best strategy i've found to structure components is the following rules:

1) Only allow components to know about what absolutely concerns them and nothing else.

2) Always ask the question when creating a component, does this component need to be "smart" or can it be "dumb".

3) On only rare occasions make a parent a "smart" component.

It's much like the SRP principle applies to classes in a that implements its inheritance through classes. `A class should only have one reason to change.` Applied to components it can be view as `A component should only have one reason to update.` The lines are a bit grey when it comes to components though, because state and props aren't always passed over the same way as classes are in a backend application, but as a general rule I think it helps.

Also, i've programmed with Vue, React, and Angular (version 5), and they are of course better at different things and have different trade offs, but all of them are great technologies. I think you can build an application that doesn't have the cascading problem that is an Angular app as well. There are technical constraints that would make one better than the other, but you only find those once you have a specific context laid out as the use case.

Hope this helps!

Side note I think this is what popularized those terms as a note of trivia: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: Gotcha.  So it sounds like yes, the cascading changes issue is indeed present with Vue when 2-way binding is used.  Is that the gist?

Comment: Essentially. Sorry for the long winded response. :)